# Unsure how to frame SQL Query for the following task

Tags: mysql, sql

[image: Tables]

I have the above mentioned tables in my database. I first receive a COURSE variable from my previous PHP page. I need to print the list of student names along with their student_Ids who haven't taken the course. For the tables above, if the variable  **I receive is A, then I need to print Jake along with his student_id**. As **Jake's student id 3, is not associaetd with Course A**.

I tried following query, which doesn't seem to work and I'm unsure where I'm wrong

```
SELECT DISTINCT T1.name, T1.student_id 
FROM Table 1 T1, Table 2 T2
WHERE T1.student_id = T2.student_id AND
T2.COURSE != :variable
ORDER BY T1.name ASC, 
         T1.student_id ASC
```

variable : A

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate that this must seem very old-fashioned, but then again, so am I...

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.*
  FROM t1 x
  LEFT
  JOIN t2 y
    ON y.student_id = x.student_id
   AND y.course = 'a'
 WHERE y.student_id IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of options. For instance, you could use a subquery:

```
SELECT name, student_id FROM t1 WHERE student_id NOT IN (SELECT student_id FROM t2 WHERE course='A')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` to find a list of students who have not taken the course:

```
SELECT * FROM T1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM T2
    WHERE T1.StudentId = T2.StudentId
        AND T2.Course = :variable
    )
ORDER BY name ASC, student_id
```